# run as administrator password contain tilde

Tags: vbscript

How can I use special character password like mine have Tilde in my password as `Ka$$1001~1`

Here is the script below, I'm unable to run the script.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.run "runas /user:administrator92 " & chr(34) & a & chr(34)
WScript.Sleep 1000 
WshShell.SendKeys "Ka$$1001~1" 'send password 
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: `SendKeys` should be avoided wherever possible, and particularly when it comes to providing admin credentials.

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), `~` is the shorthand for `{Enter}` (the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key). Put special characters in curly braces:

`{+}` `{^}` `{%}` `{~}` `{(}` `{)}` `{[}` `{]}` `{{}` `{}}`

So your line will be as following:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "Ka$$1001{~}1" 'send password
```

Comment: On second thought: don't use `SendKeys` in the first place.